# Initialize Admin SDK with credentials depending on environment

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm new to Node.js, Firebase Cloud Functions and TypeScript.

My goal is to make a cloud function that is a http-endpoint, where the client can authenticate with Firebase. I want the cloud function to return a custom access token if the function succeeds.

I'm using two Firebase project as different environments (`development` and `production`). I figured out that I need to initialize the Admin SDK with the `ServiceAccountKey.json`. My issue is that I have two different ServiceAccountKey-files depending what environment the function is running on.

I've added an configuration variable describing which environment is actively running. I've done so by running: `firebase functions:config:set app.environment="production"`

Then my plan was to derive the path to the right ServiceAccountKey by checking this configuration.

Here is my entire index.ts file.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceAccountKeyPath = functions.config().app.environment === 'development' ? '../mojnz-development-key.json' : '../mojnz-production-key.json';
const serviceAccount = require(serviceAccountKeyPath);

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://mojnz-dev.firebaseio.com"
});

export const testFunc = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

    const berp = "123"

    admin.auth().createCustomToken(berp).then((value) => {
        console.log("Did create custom token:", value)
        response.sendStatus(200)
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error creating custom token:", error)
        response.sendStatus(500)
    })
})
```

I'm looking for answers to:

**Why isn't it possible to read the configuration variable at that point?**

**How is the best practice for initializing modules depending on environment variables?**

**Edit**
When I serve the functions locally (like so: `firebase serve --only functions`). I get error:

> i  functions: Preparing to emulate functions.
>
> ⚠  functions: Failed to load functions source code. Ensure that you have the latest SDK by running npm i --save firebase-functions inside the functions directory.
>
> ⚠  functions: Error from emulator. Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'environment' of undefined
>      at Object. (/Users/mojnz/Git/mojnz/functions/lib/index.js:7:35)
>      at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
>      at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>      at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>      at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
>      at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
>      at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
>      at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>      at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/triggerParser.js:21:11
>      at Object. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/triggerParser.js:61:3)

I did update the SDK with `npm i --save firebase-functions`.

Comment: Did you deploy your functions after running `functions:config:set`?

Comment: I didn't at first, but now I've tried it. I still get the same errors (I've added more details in the post) when trying to test the functions with `serve`. But! It seems to work when I test the functions that has been deployed to the servers. I can see in the console that the custom token is logged. How come I get this error only when running `serve`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use environment variables when testing locally (with `serve` or `functions:shell`), there is currently an extra step you have to take to make them show up.  It's [documented on this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator):

> If you're using custom functions configuration variables, first run
>   the command to get your custom config (run this within the functions
>   directory), and then run the shell:
>
> ```
> firebase functions:config:get > .runtimeconfig.json firebase
> functions:shell
> ```

Every time you want to change your vars, you'll have to re-create the `.runtimeconfig.json` file in your `functions` folder.